# Where on the result of a stored proc not working

Tags: entity-framework, function, frameworks, import

I'm using EF4.0 and have a function import defined to return me a complex type that is modelled on my stored procedure. I can execute the stored proc fine and get my results back correctly and all of my filter work, except for 1.

```
result = result.Where(item => item.LANID == filter.LanId);
```

the value of filter.LandId in the debugger is "HO\\UserX", however Text Visualizer tells me the actual value is "HO\UserX" (which is correct and what it should be). The LANID column that the stored proc returns does contain that exact value as well ("HO\UserX"), however after my where, the result count is 0.

Does anyone know what EF is doing to filter this list and why is this particular filter screwing up? I assume somewhere something is being escaped incorrectly but I cannot figure out what or where.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

EF is doing nothing. If `result` is result of stored procedure it means that all entities were loaded to your application and filtering is done by Linq-to-objects. The debugger shows you `\\` because `\` is special character for escape sequences so if you want to use `\` character in string it must be escaped `\\`.

Comment: Hi Ladislav, I understand and I have tried filter.LanId = filter.LanId.Replace(@"\", @"\\") and then executing the where, but the result is still empty.

Comment: Is it problem only with this single string or with every string containing `\` character?

Comment: Only the LandId field has these \'s in them and it is the only field that is causing me the issue. I will try updating a different field to contain \ and see if a filter works on that.

Comment: if I update a different field to contain a \, the filter works against that field correctly. I think the answer must be the way in which I am getting the LanId field in the filter.

Comment: Ok, nevermind - I'm a complete idiot. The entries in the DB all have trailing spaces and somewhere in the UI, the filter is bring Trimmed, removing the spaces.

Comment: That was what I thought about when I asked if it works with other fields ;)